# Combine 3 hashes into an array inside my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller with 3 hashes I want to combine into 1 object to pass to a view.

```
@feedorders = current_user.orders.order("created_at DESC")
@feedcustomers = current_user.customers.order("created_at DESC")
@feedbooks = current_user.books.order("created_at DESC")
```

How should I go back doing this?

Comment: what type of object? a hash an array an active record a class you created?

Comment: Well I'd like to combine the three hashes into one array to pass to the view and display.

Comment: Can you add more detail of the type of display. By default these instance variables are already "shared" (i.e. accessible) from the view, you don't need to "pass" them. So, it comes down to what you actually want to do with them; what's the display logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@combined = {orders: @feedorders, customers: @feedcustomers, books: @feedbooks}
```

Then you can get the orders with

```
@combined[:orders]
```

Edit:

If you just want to get one array and do not care that the different kind of objects go mixed, then you could just do

```
@combined = @feedorders + @feedcustomers + @feedbooks
```

It just may be a bit more difficulty to work with such an array in the view.

Comment: Does this combine them all into an array I can print everything out in a view?

Comment: Yup, you would do @combined[:orders][0] or @combined[:orders].first for each individual one.

Comment: Wouldn't @combined[:orders] just show me the @feedorders?  I want to list everything in the array out in one table.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding them together is probably the simplest solution, you might want to restructure how you store it too. It seems like you want them ordered as well, which means you should pass the sum to a sort function like this:

```
@combined = (@feedorders + @feedcustomers + @feedbooks).sort { |x, y| x.created_at <=> y.created_at}
```